# Getting error after openURL on appcelerator Titanium v 9

Tags: ios, titanium, openurl

I'm working on Titanium project build on sdk v9 for ios platform, and I'm getting this error when opening an external url with this function Titanium.Platform.openURL :

```
[ERROR] :  Script Error {
[ERROR] :      message = "undefined is not an object";
[ERROR] :      type = TypeError;
[ERROR] :  }
```

the problem is it's not telling where the issue is, can any one help please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using `setInterval` in the pause/resume events?

Comment: No, shall I use this?

Comment: no, but there was the same question in TiSlack by a user that had this error in combination with setInterval. In case you are not using 9.0.3 try to update to that version.

Comment: I'm already using the version 9.0.2 , will that make any difference?

Comment: 9.0.3 not 9.0.2.

Comment: @hamza_rhd Were you able to figure out a resolution? I'm facing the same issue, any code executed after a Ti.Platform.openURL causes the "undefined is not an object" error with no stack trace. I tried upgrading to 9.0.3 but it made no difference.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that this is a Titanium bug... I've logged a ticket with a repro here: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/COMM-57

Comment: @Justin of course it didn't make any difference, i couldn't find the best solution, the good thing that this issue don't appear on production and didn't make any crash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get around this error (which seems like a Titanium bug) by specifying the second and third args of the openURL command:

```
Ti.Platform.openURL('http://maps.apple.com/maps?q=' + destinationAddress, null, () => { });
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!! Thanks a lot

Comment: Works fine. Thank you and +1 for the JIRA ticket!